# Copying files with spaces in the name using a shell script

Tags: linux, shell, filenames, cp, mv

I am using this script to mv all the files from a shared directory to another directory:

```
cd /share
while :
do
  for allfiles in $(find /share/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname "*" -mmin +1);
do
  sudo mv "$allfiles" /schoolstore/
  done
  sleep 15s
done
```

But, I get error when a filen contains a space within its name, where can I fix the script to get it to work for all files name?

Comment: Temporarily change $IFS: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1724032/shell-variable-with-spaces-quoting-for-single-command-line-option

Comment: Your code differs from your description. Which is correct?

Comment: [Why your code doesn't work](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the other question referenced in my comment here is my suggestion (not tested)

```
cd /share

do
  for allfiles in $(find /share/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname "*" -mmin +1);
  do
    aveIFS="$IFS"; IFS=''; ls $file; 
    sudo mv "$allfiles" /schoolstore/
    IFS="$saveIFS"
  done
```

There are probably ways to optimize it, and I removed the `while` part of your code since it seems like that would not halt.

Needless to say, backup all your files before running this type of code (or any code for that matter).

Alternatively, instead of changing $IFS it might be possible to to this operation only with one `find` command using the `-exec` flag. Here is what I mean (again, untested):

```
find /share/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname "*" -mmin +1 -exec mv {} /schoolstore/ \;
```